# Can one fulfil a value?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example, 'It seems that fulfilling the value of altruism helps them feel their lives are meaningful.'

Comment: The very simple answer is "No".  The sentence is simply badly-written.

Comment: values cannot be fulfilled: goals, aims, objectives, targets etc.

Comment: Abstract concepts cannot be fulfilled. But they can be *brought to fruition* (realized).

Comment: @Mazura "But they can be brought to fruition (realized)". I've already mentioned one of the definitions dictionaries give for fulfil is some variant of "to realise", "make real", "convert into reality", "bring into realisation".

Comment: Also, I've included a few quotations of "fulfil(l) the values". I understand most of you consider it to be incorrect. Still, I've added them just for fun.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. No - because a value is an idea, a concept. Yes - because we are fulfilling something that matches this value.

For example, I think my watch has a value of 20 dollars. However, it can never be 20 dollars because a watch is a watch and I can only exchange it for 20 dollars.

However, by exchanging the watch for money, I fulfill my idea that the value of the watch is 20 dollars.

Language is language, and to explain all that each time is time consuming, so we say that we 'fulfill a value'.

Comment: The third paragraph here is completely wrong.  You would not be "fulfilling" your "idea" in question.   You're possibly thinking of "confirming an idea", or something else?  Fulfill (look in a dictionary) means "complete" or "finish" or "wrap-up".

Comment: @Fattie Again, you're imposing your own narrow definition of fulfil: "1. To bring into actuality; effect or make real:" / "to carry out, or bring to realization, as a prophecy or promise. " / "Achieve or realize (something desired, promised, or predicted)

Comment: Trevor, I'm going to upvote your answer because I feel that the downvote was completely unfair based on the reasoning given, namely that an idea can't be fulfilled. Browsing a number of dictionaries one can easily see that this is not the case. This user seems to have come along and with their narrow understanding of word meanings and has decided to impose their own meaning of English and downvoted both our answers. I find the first statement of their own answer completely absurd, but given that my habit is that I don't downvote, I didn't.

Comment: An "idea" can not be fulfilled; a "goal" can be fulfilled.  A "dream" (in the sense of a goal) can be fulfilled.  In the third para here, "idea" is simply being used in the dictionary sense "theory" / "belief" / "guess".  You can **confirm** a theory/belief/guess.  You can't "fulfill" a theory/belief/guess.

Comment: Note that the word "idea" can be used simply as a simile for "plan".  ("I had an idea to have fish for lunch" is just slang for "I had a plan to use fish for lunch.")  You can indeed fulfill a plan (such as "my plan is, have fish for lunch.")

Comment: @Fattie - so a dream can and an idea cannot? So dreams are never ideas, as in 'I have a dream of owning a shed'?

Comment: Hi Trevor, it's incredibly common in English that words have more than one (totally different) meaning.  (If you are a native English speaker, it is remarkable if you are not aware of this.)  "dream" has a number of utterly different meanings.  A "dream" {1} is the things that happen in your sleep.  You can not "fulfill" a dream {1}, it is meaningless. A "dream" {2} is a goal.  You can fulfill a goal.

Comment: Regarding "idea", "idea" {1} is a belief, guess, theory.  (Your believe the watch is worth $20.)  You cannot "fulfill" a guess or theory.  You can prove it, confirm it, etc.   "idea" {2} usage is to mean "plan" ("We had an idea to have lunch at McDonalds")  You can fulfill a plan.

Comment: @Fattie Again you're ignoring the dictionary definitions of to realise, effect, actualise and make real. Nothing to do with completion necessarily. A value, which is an abstract concept, can be realised. I'm not going to quote them again I believe I've done so about 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

Wowie, what a train wreck this has been so far. He said, she said. People quoting conflicting dictionary definitions at each other and whatnot. Thinking up convoluted arguments and getting all agitated at one another.

Well then. Let them have their fun. Meanwhile the rest of us, how about we'll just have a quick look at the reality of the language.

Here is the complete list of things that humanity has managed to fulfill so far according to the actual usage stats from the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

```
RESPONSIBILITIES    3    
REQUIREMENTS        3    
PROMISES            3    
ROLE                3    
PROMISE             2    
FUNCTION            2    
COMMITMENTS         2    
ROLES               2    
CONDITIONS          2    
WISH                1    
WILL                1    
TASK                1    
PURPOSES            1    
DREAMS              1    
DEMANDS             1    
DEMAND              1    
CRITERIA            1    
POSITION            1    
PLAN                1    
OBLIGATIONS         1    
NEED                1    
IDEA                1
```

And here is an even more generous list of the top 200 nouns that ever follow *fulfill* in the entire [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

```
PROMISE             209  
DREAM               124  
MISSION             112  
OBLIGATIONS         104  
NEEDS               95   
ROLE                89   
PROMISES            85   
REQUIREMENTS        77   
DUTIES              74   
DREAMS              64   
EXPECTATIONS        63   
POTENTIAL           63   
OBLIGATION          62   
RESPONSIBILITIES    61   
ROLES               50   
NEED                45   
DESTINY             45   
COMMITMENTS         45   
RESPONSIBILITY      44   
DUTY                38   
COMMITMENT          35   
FUNCTION            32   
GOALS               32   
PURPOSE             32   
MANDATE             31   
DESIRES             27   
REQUIREMENT         27   
OBJECTIVES          27   
VISION              27   
GOAL                26   
FUNCTIONS           25   
CONTRACT            25   
PART                23   
DEMANDS             22   
CONDITIONS          21   
PROPHECY            21   
PURPOSES            19   
DESIRE              18   
LIFE                17   
AMBITIONS           15   
WISHES              15   
PLEDGE              15   
TASK                14   
REQUEST             14   
OBJECTIVE           13   
CRITERIA            13   
HOPES               13   
FANTASIES           12   
MISSIONS            12   
TASKS               12   
TERMS               11   
ORDERS              11   
REQUESTS            11   
FANTASY             11   
COURSE              11   
ASPIRATIONS         11   
CONTRACTS           10   
FATHER              10   
OATH                10   
WISH                10   
VOW                 10   
STATE               9    
PRESIDENT           9    
DEMAND              9    
AMBITION            9    
LAW                 8    
LEADERSHIP          8    
PLEDGES             8    
ORDER               8    
MOTHER              7    
AGENDA              7    
COMMUNITY           7    
CHILDHOOD           7    
AGREEMENT           6    
ASSIGNMENT          6    
INFORMATION         6    
FAMILY              6    
PROPHECIES          6    
QUOTAS              6    
TEACHING            6    
SIDE                6    
WILL                6    
TRUST               6    
SECURITY            5    
RIGHTS              5    
PLANS               5    
PRODUCTION          5    
PROFESSION          5    
NUMBER              5    
EXPECTATION         5    
END                 5    
IDEALS              5    
GRADUATION          5    
LONGING             5    
CHARGE              5    
COMMANDMENT         5    
COMMISSIONS         5    
DEFINITION          5    
CONDITION           5    
CALLING             4    
CHARTER             4    
CAREER              4    
AGENCY              4    
AGREEMENTS          4    
MANDATES            4    
LIVES               4    
LEGACY              4    
HEART               4    
HOPE                4    
DESTINIES           4    
EDUCATION           4    
PARTY               4    
PEOPLE              4    
READER              4    
PUBLIC              4    
PLAN                4    
SCHOOL              4    
SCRIPTURE           4    
SENSE               4    
VOWS                4    
VOCATION            4    
VISIONS             3    
WHIMS               3    
RIGHT               3    
TREATY              3    
WORK                3    
SCIENCE             3    
TEACHER             3    
SPONSOR             3    
STANDARD            3    
STANDARDS           3    
STUDENT             3    
STUDENTS            3    
RANGE               3    
PARENTS             3
MANAGEMENT          3    
MR                  3    
ELECTION            3    
ENERGY              3    
GENDER              3    
IDEAL               3    
HEALTH              3    
GUIDELINES          3    
INTENTION           3    
JOB                 3    
BUSINESS            3    
CHILD               3    
COMPANY             3    
COMMISSION          3    
COMMANDS            3    
CHILDREN            3    
CHURCH              3    
CORE                3    
CRITERION           3    
DAY                 3    
DEGREE              3    
CRIME               3    
DEAL                3    
DESIGN              2    
DEATHBED            2    
DEBT                2    
CUSTOMER            2    
CONSUMER            2    
CITIZENSHIP         2    
CITY                2    
CLASS               2    
CHOICE              2    
COMMANDMENTS        2    
CLIENT              2    
COLLEGE             2    
COMMAND             2    
CHARACTERISTICS     2    
BULK                2    
ASSESSMENT          2    
BODY                2    
AIM                 2    
AIMS                2    
ACHIEVEMENT         2    
JUDGMENT            2    
INTENTIONS          2    
INTEREST            2    
INTERESTS           2    
KIND                2    
INTENT              2    
LICENSE             2    
LOAN                2    
LOT                 2    
HISTORY             2    
HUMANITY            2    
IMAGE               2    
IMPERATIVE          2    
INDIVIDUAL          2    
INJUNCTION          2    
GALA                2    
GOVERNANCE          2    
GOVERNMENT          2    
FUNCTIONALITY       2    
EXECUTIVE           2   
POWERS              1
```

Note that this list includes not just direct objects of the verb *fulfill*, but just any nouns that follow it, i.e. also noun modifiers of its actual objects. You can't really fulfill a *mister* or a *deathbed* or a *college* or a *mother*. But you can fulfill *Mr Smith's requirements*, or a *deathbed wish*, or a *college's needs*, or your *mother's dream*. That's how all these weird hits end up on the list. I was thinking about cleaning these up, and might still do that as time permits, but in the mean time they actually help drive home the following point:

**The word "value" is nowhere to be seen.**

So not only has nobody ever fulfilled a value. Nobody has ever so much as fulfilled a value requirement or a value goal or a value need or a value anything.

In conclusion, what you have is not English as she is spoke or wrote. You can't use it. If you did, you might actually be the very first person, on either side of the pond, to have ever done so.

Comment: This fulfills every requirement of a data-based answer.  Surely this can all just be migrated to English Language Learners now?

Comment: The corpora results are goods, but the conclusion is just wrong. Some words that are synonyms of the ones in the list don't appear: "target", "endeavour", "undertaking", "chore", "office", "pursuit", "scheme", "guarantee", "assurance". I find it worrying to hear you imply that because a word doesn't appear in that list that nobody's ever fulfilled [that word]. That would mean nobody's ever fulfilled a "target" or "undertaking". I don't want to insist that "fulfil a value" is acceptable, I've looked through different meanings and challenged my views, I'm taking a logical approach.

Comment: @Zebrafish it's not me implying that, it's all speakers of the language collectively saying it to our faces. If the OP asks if they can shave a car, we look through the corpora, and there are no hits, then we can, and must, say "that's not what people actually do, you just might be the first person ever." You are free to shave *your* car, and fulfill *your* value, and lick *your* mathematics. The question here is not whether you can do as you please, the question is whether others are just as pleased to do it. And they are not. If that worries you, excellent. Because it should.

Comment: People approaching this logically is precisely the issue. I say as much in the opening paragraph. If we approach things logically, then "I'm on the bus" is not English. It must be "I'm in the bus". And nobody can possibly say "my father lived in London when he was five", because when he was five, he wasn't their father. No father in the world entire was ever five. And people just don't ride on buses. That's what logic gives you. But this question is not about logic, it's about language. And so it's the language that we must be looking at.

Comment: If the question were "can I fulfill a requirement", nobody here would so much as open a dictionary. Everybody would just say "sure mate, I hear it all the time". That would be our answer in its entirety. The very fact that people feel compelled to appeal to logic and construct argument chains and go hunting for loopholes in definitions is a dead giveaway that something's not right. And the fact that other people still object after all that work is done, is all the answer the OP needs. Their question is, would people object to what I have. Well yes, they would. Here are some that do.

Comment: I feel you missed my point about approaching this logically. Applying logic doesn't mean concluding that "on the bus" means on the roof of the bus, as you said. That would be being excessively literal. It means applying one of the definitions of "on" and finding that it can indeed mean to be in a vehicle of transport. That's the sort of logic I mean to apply. One of the common definitions of "fulfil" is "to realise", "make real", "convert into reality", "bring into realisation", this is the meaning I test when considering if it can apply to a specific object.

Comment: My issue with you saying that no one has ever fulfilled a value, that it's not English and that they can't use it is not the mere the fact that you said it, but that you did so based on those corpus results. I've shown this reasoning isn't satisfactory. This reasoning implies to fulfil a target or undertaking is not English and can't be used. Finally, I understand the question exactly as it's asked, "Can one fulfil a value?" I've answered that question strictly. How idiomatic it is or advisable to say is another matter I addressed in my answer, ie., I admit it's very uncommon and unidiomatic.

Comment: Well, I didn't go into this thinking "nonono, you can't shave a car". And I didn't go into it thinking "of course you can, duh". I figured, "gee, no idea". I read every answer and every comment. And I still had no idea. What *do* people do to their cars? So I went and asked the people. All of them. Ready to accept that everyone shaves cars all the time. But it just so turns out that they don't. You are still free to shave yours. And to fulfill all your targets and undertakings. And to ride in the bus. And to not be aware that other people don't actually do that. But I am aware now. Is all.

Comment: No problem. By the way, just for fun I've included some quotes from books, articles, etc, from both BrE and AmE. I've pointed out that, from the looks of it, folk round these parts consider it incorrect.

Comment: "English as she is spoke or wrote"? Sounds positively piratical and reminds me of a "stove boat".  Logic is really not germane to these questions.  Reasoning and rationality based on one's internalized corpora is.

Comment: @Lambie wait, "English as she is spoke" does not remind you of ["English as she is spoke"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_As_She_Is_Spoke)?

Comment: Oh dear, I cannot ***believe*** I didn't know about that book. Shame on me. (especially with my fluency in Portuguese and French.) However, I know a more modern one:  The Cow Went to the Swamp (A Vaca Foi Pro Brejo). So, I'm not a total loser. [:)]

Answer (score 0):

> fulfil
>   1. To bring into actuality; effect or make real: fulfilled their promises; fulfilled her dream.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fulfil)
>
> 2a : to put into effect : execute
>   3a : to convert into reality
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fulfill)

Altruism <s>can mean</s> can describe an act done for another selflessly. Helping an old lady cross the road can be considered altruism. Or it can be an idea, philosophy, tendency, or even a value. I doubt anyone thinks that "altruistic values" is nonsensical or a strange term. As the definition above says, to fulfil can mean to bring to actuality, meaning to bring to reality. So I don't see why altruism as a value can't be fulfilled. Though most of the time this meaning of value is seen in the plural, "values".

> altruism
>   1. the principle or practice of unselfish concern for the welfare of others
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/altruism)

Notice it says the "principle or practice", much like what I said, ie., the "act", or the "philosophy" or "inclination", or even belief and value.

> 'It seems that fulfilling the value of altruism helps them feel their
>   lives are meaningful.'

Edit: Please note, many users have expressed their disapproval of "value" being an object of "fulfil". I somewhat understand why they feel this way. The argument seems to be that the verb fulfil means to complete or finish, and therefore things such as plans and goals can be fulfilled, but not values and ideas, and that saying such a thing makes no sense. More recently an argument has been made based on English corpora results. However I feel it's acceptable, and I've given the relevant definitions to explain why I think it's fine. However note that it is in fact very unidiomatic, as the results I've seen show. I'm also tempted to delete this answer entirely as I seem to be in the minority, and will probably get downvoted. I've given two alternatives at the end you may want to consider.

I would say that altruistic acts do make a person feel better, but the point you make about altruism bringing meaning to people's lives in my opinion seems to detract from the true meaning of altruism because true altruism most accurately means doing something without consideration for oneself, that is, it's motivated for concern for others.

Having said that, you may consider using other terms:

- putting into action one's values of altruism
- actualising one's values of altruism.

Just for fun, here are a couple of examples I found (note I'm not advocating its use, most users here seem to consider this usage incorrect)

> The H2OK program aims to increase awareness that reducing organic matter entering storm drains can improve local water quality, giving residents a way to fulfill the values they hold about protecting water quality.
>   [Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America journal article, 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6099879/)
>
> Resolved: a parliamentary system of government would better fulfill the values underlying the American Constitution.
>   [1987 National Speech & Debate Tournament debate topic](https://www.speechanddebate.org/topics/)
>
> Thus, the issue for rights theorists adopting the dignity and autonomy
>   perspective... is whether the law offers employees enough job security
>   in order to fulfil the values they are advocating.
>  [Perspectives
>   on Labour Law, Cambridge University Press, 2004](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=hxln_-RqFVEC&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=%22fulfil%20the%20values%22&source=bl&ots=Q_xJRuTN-1&sig=u-ZodvRTMR7V2PWys3FfF6KyIvc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwict9ur4abeAhXKuo8KHWJCDyYQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22fulfil%20the%20values%22&f=false)
>
> ...Ireland should be part of that initiative not just out of
>   pragmatism but also to fulfil the values associated with EU
>   membership.
>  [The Irish Times opinion piece, January 2018](https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/eu-defence-co-operation-is-no-threat-to-irish-neutrality-1.3343293)
>
> The commitments described in this Privacy Policy fulfil the values,
>   the principles of action and behaviour of CDL and are
>   established...
>  [Caudan Arts Centre Privacy Policy](https://www.caudanlive.com/privacy-policy/)

Comment: This answer is basically completely wrong from top to bottom.   For example, the first sentence *"Altruism can mean an act done for another selflessly"* is totally incorrect.  The *act* is not altruism.  You're completely confusing adjectives with nouns to begin with.  Say I helped a granny, you could not say "That was a nice altruism." The sentence as stated ... ie the sentence *in the question* ... is quite simply totally incorrect.  "fulfilling the value of altruism" is a nonsensical phrase.

Comment: @Fattie So you disagree with the definition of Collins Dictionary on "altruism", and in addition also disagree to the the definition of "fulfil", " To bring into actuality; effect or make real". You're simply imposing your own narrow definitions, which is quite obnoxious. I never said to use "an altruism", don't use strawmen. I merely said what the definitions I quoted have said, that to fulfil is to realise, bring to reality or actuality, and that altruism can be the practice of altruism. So yes, ideas can be fulfilled (ie., realised, brought into action), as the dictionaries say.

Comment: "Altruism can mean an act done for another selflessly" is incorrect. The act is not altruism. You can not say "That was a nice altruism."  You could say "that was a nice act of altruism."

Comment: @Fattie "The act is not altruism". It obviously is, as the act is the practice of altruism, as defined. Again, I did not advise to say "an altruism". Doing voluntary work is an act of altruism, is the practice of altruism, and yes, is altruism itself. A charity donation, which is an act of altruism, is altruism in itself.

Comment: You (obviously) can not say "That was a nice altruism." You could say "that was a nice act of altruism."  Very simple.  Your confusion in the previous comment is:  "A charity donation, which is an act of altruism, is altruism in itself."  Certainly, but you can't *use the word* "altruism" to refer to one specific "act of altruism".  You can not say "That was a nice altruism." You could say "that was a nice act of altruism."

Comment: @Fattie If you admit that a charity donation is altruism, then why do you object to saying that altruism can be an act done for another?

Comment: ???   To literally copy and paste, you can't use the word "altruism" to refer to one specific "act of altruism". You can not say "That was a nice altruism." You could say "that was a nice act of altruism."

Comment: Note BTW that your sentence fragment "Doing voluntary work is an act of altruism..." is not really correct.  Doing *a specific* voluntary thing, is indeed "an act".  "Doing voluntary work" is like saying "doing programming".  bye for now.

Comment: @Fattie That's not true. Tossing a coin to a beggar is an act of altruism. Tossing a coin to a beggar is altruism because altruism, as I've quoted, can include "the practice" itself. So in this case the act of altruism is altruism.  You mustn't have actually looked at the definitions I quoted.  And your digression about voluntary work not being an act, that's wrong too. "I did voluntary work on the weekend" most likely means I did many different things, but it can be seen as one act of selfless voluntarism. This just further shows how restrictive you are with your definitions.

Comment: hi @Zebrarish   , the phrase "voluntary work" is usually a collective noun.  (Just like say, doing "good".)   Is "doing good" a specific single numerated act?  No.  In any event ............ Simply look at the question title - the answer is "no".    You can't "fulfill" a "value" - it is open-ended.  It would be just like saying "fulfill nice" or "fulfill green".

Comment: You wrote, '"I did voluntary work on the weekend" most likely means I did many different things, but it can be seen as one act of selfless voluntarism.'  Quite right. *If* it was *one* thing, and you then want to refer to that *one thing* in a sentence calling for a discrete unit, you'd have to use an English term that allows use with a discrete unit.

Comment: @Fattie "doing good" is in the progressive aspect, it's continuous and doesn't designate a particular start or end. Saying "I did good" can easily be described as having done a good act. As to your advice to me to simply look at the title, that's exactly what I did, and I juxtaposed the word fulfil against the dictionary definitions that say to actualise, realise, make real and effect. These do not require bringing something to a conclusion. And I've quoted or paraphrased these words about 6 six times now. These meanings are rather simple, but I feel you choose to ignore them.

Comment: The adjective is altruistic. An altruistic act.

Comment: @Lambie Yeah I know, I think I used the word. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @Zebrafish  No, you didn't. I just fail to see why obvious questions give rise to such a prolonged discussion.  This site doesn't handle these questions very well....if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Lambie "No, you didn't". Oh you're too kind. My opinion on the matter is not shared at all by most, including you. The prolonged discussion to what you think is a clear-cut answer came about because I expressed an opinion that nearly everyone else disagreed with. If I had shut up, things would have been simple, but I had to speak my mind. So it's mainly my fault. I tried to improve my answer to make my case and to explain why people think it's wrong. I even provided quotations of use that most people think is incorrect, just to give perspective. I'm always happy to be wrong. Well, kinda.